# scrapy limit amount of requests for domain

Tags: python, scrapy, generator

```
import scrapy
from urllib.parse import urljoin


class MyCrawlSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    LIMIT_OF_DOMAIN = 100

    def start_requests(self):
        with open('links.txt', 'r') as f:
            urls = f.read().split('\n')
        #urls=['https://www.google.com/search?q=hello+world','https://yahoo.com']
        for url in urls:
            # remove empty links
            if not url:
                continue
            sub_item = {'main_url': url, 'index_of_domain': 0}
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse, meta=sub_item,)

    def parse(self,response):
        main_url = response.meta['main_url']
        index_of_domain = response.meta['index_of_domain']
        for url in response.xpath('//a[@href] | //article[@href]'):
            href = url.xpath('@href').extract_first()
            url = urljoin(main_url, href.strip())
            if index_of_domain >= self.LIMIT_OF_DOMAIN:
                break
            index_of_domain += 1
            sub_item = {'main_url': main_url, 'index_of_domain': index_of_domain}
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse, meta=sub_item, )
```

currently my limit`LIMIT_OF_DOMAIN` is not working as I wanted, somehow it keeps crawling much after my 100 limit. I have searched the scrapy docs but couldn't find limit for domain, How can I fix this?

Ideally what I want for each link in `starting_requests` to get 100 request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class CurrentValue(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = 0

    def increment(self):
        self.value += 1
class YourSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    def start_requets(self):
        obj = CurrentValue()
        #your code
        sub_item = {'current_url': url, 'main_url': url, 'index_of_domain': obj}

    def parse(self,response):
        obj = response.meta['index_of_domain']
        for url in urls:
            obj.increment()
```

you simply need another class to store value for each starting link